# android layout xml across multiple files

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

For easier maintenance, I would like to use multiple XML files for a screen, especially since I have parts that exclude each other depending on the user action. So parts of the layout have visibility gone or visible. These parts I would like to have in multiple files and then one file where I only reference to them. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `<include/>` element to have sub-xml files:

```
<LinearLayout ... >
   <include layout="@layout/header" />
   <include layout="@layout/content" />
   <include layout="@layout/footer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This will allow you to make use of re-usability.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [< include/>](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) tag to reuse layouts. you can add multiple layout xml in one layout using this tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can call the setContentView() method that displays your XML file whenever the user performs an action.